# Why does "view-source:" show unrendered directives?

Tags: vue.js

I have a static site with a couple of pages with vue.js.

The problem is when I open the source of a page "view-source:", I can see unrendered directives. I don't remember I had it on other sites. Am I missing something?

```
Name: ((contacts.name))
...
<colorpicker :color="contacts.color" v-model="contacts.color"></colorpicker>
...
<.. directive=`${something}`...>
```

---

**edit**, It won't help but here's another example.
I use `((` delimiter insted of `{{`

This is how I see the page when viewing it through `view-source:https://....`:

```
                  <div class="control is-expanded">
                    <div class="select is-fullwidth">
                      <select v-model="k.s">
                        <option v-for="so in m.so" :value="so">(( so ))</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <colorpicker :color="k.c" v-model="k.c"></colorpicker>
```

Here's a screenshot of another part of the page:
[image]

Comment: Could you share some code samples? Do you have this unrendered stuff for a short amount of time or..? Probably https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-cloak this can help

Comment: No, not on page. Everything looks fine. Its only when I right click and then select view page source.